# how to calculate no. of times xsl:choose statements executes inside xsl:for-each?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to fetch all the ttype and vendor.id, if **assemblyCustom/revisionCustom/entityTypeCode** and **assemblyCustom/revisionCustom/usCode** matches to any **ttypes-config/item/enityTypeCode/** and **ttypes-config/item/usCode** respectively

This is my input xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<combined-xml>
    <assemblyCustom>
        <revisionCustom>
            <entityTypeCode>C</entityTypeCode>
            <usCode>G</usCode>
        </revisionCustom>
    </assemblyCustom>
    <ttypes-config>
        <item>
            <vendor.id>111</vendor.id>
            <ttype>AAA</ttype>
            <enityTypeCode>
                <item>C</item>
                <item>D</item>
                <item>E</item>
                <item>F</item>
            </enityTypeCode>
            <usCode>
                <item>G</item>
                <item>H</item>
                <item>I</item>
                <item>J</item>
                <item>K</item>
                <item>L</item>
                <item>M</item>
            </usCode>
        </item>
        <item>
            <vendor.id>222</vendor.id>
            <ttype>BBB</ttype>
            <enityTypeCode>
                <item>N</item>
                <item>C</item>
            </enityTypeCode>
            <usCode>
                <item>G</item>
            </usCode>
        </item>
        <item>
            <vendor.id>333</vendor.id>
            <ttype>CCC</ttype>
            <enityTypeCode>
                <item>Q</item>
                <item>R</item>
            </enityTypeCode>
            <usCode>
                <item>S</item>
            </usCode>
        </item>
        <item>
            <vendor.id>444</vendor.id>
            <ttype>DDD</ttype>
            <enityTypeCode>
                <item>T</item>
                <item>U</item>
            </enityTypeCode>
            <usCode>
                <item>V</item>
            </usCode>
        </item>
        
        <item>
            <vendor.id>555</vendor.id>
            <ttype>EEEs</ttype>
            <enityTypeCode>
                <item>W</item>
                </enityTypeCode>
            <usCode>
                <item>X</item>
                <item>Y</item>
            </usCode>
        </item>
    </ttypes-config>
</combined-xml>
```

if given condition matches, then output should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ttype-output>
    <ttype>AAA</ttype>
    <vendor.id>111</vendor.id>
    <ttype>BBB</ttype>
    <vendor.id>222</vendor.id>
   
</ttype-output>
```

If doesn't matches for any ttypes-config/item/ then output should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ttype-output>
    <ttype>Default</ttype>
    <vendor.id>000</vendor.id>
</ttype-output>
```

Following is my xsl file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="entityTypeCode">
        <xsl:value-of select="combined-xml/assemblyCustom/revisionCustom/entityTypeCode"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="usCode">
        <xsl:value-of select="combined-xml/assemblyCustom/revisionCustom/usCode"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/combined-xml/ttypes-config/item">
        <xsl:variable name="current_entityTypeCode">
            <xsl:value-of select="enityTypeCode"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="current_usCode">
            <xsl:value-of select="usCode"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test="contains($current_entityTypeCode, $entityTypeCode) and contains($current_usCode, $usCode)">
            <ttype>
                <xsl:value-of select="ttype"/>
            </ttype>
            <vendor.id>
                <xsl:value-of select="vendor.id"/>
            </vendor.id>
        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ttype-output>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/combined-xml/ttypes-config/item"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </ttype-output>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am able to fetch ttypes and vendor id based on condition but how can i apply xsl:otherwise condition inside for-each as default ttype should only be printed if condition doesn't satisfy for any of the iteration.

Comment: I could not understand from your description whether an item needs to satisfy both conditions or just either one.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly (big IF!), you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="entity" match="ttypes-config/item" use="enityTypeCode/item" />
<xsl:key name="us" match="ttypes-config/item" use="usCode/item" />

<xsl:template match="/combined-xml">
    <xsl:variable name="match-entity" select="key('entity', assemblyCustom/revisionCustom/entityTypeCode)" />
    <xsl:variable name="match-us" select="key('us', assemblyCustom/revisionCustom/usCode)" />
    <ttype-output>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$match-entity">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$match-entity/ttype"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <ttype>Default</ttype>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$match-us">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$match-us/vendor.id"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <vendor.id>000</vendor.id>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </ttype-output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```